# Visual studio - One click publishing, web deploy, problem with non dll files

Tags: deployment

I have a simple web application built with several DLLs created on others projects in the same solution. This dlls access some text, xml files or other for
information. This elements have their property "Copy To Output Directory" define to "Copy Always". When I built the web application, everthing is present on the "bin" output directory and everything's fine.

However, when I publish the same application to a server with the "web deploy" install feature, my XML, txt files are NOT copied to the
server machine's application folder. All other files are copied just fine.
Can someone tell me why all those files are not included in the "click once" and why all the "bin" output content is not published ?

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and setting "Items to deploy" of "Package/Publish Web" is define to "Only files needed to run this application" ?

Thank you for any response,

Ben

Comment: I have the same problem, I use VS10 "Web One Click Publish" feature, it does not copy files like .resx etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  Include the files in the Visual Studio project/solution.  Right-click the file, select Properties.  Set Build Action to "Content."  Then rebuild the deployment package to see if that works.